# error accessing path: buckets/tmp

Tags: stellar-core

Two days after installing stellar-core, when I run ./stellar-core, I had this error:
Got an exception: error accessing path: buckets/tmp [main.cpp:671]
How can i handle it?

Answer (score 2):

It might be an issue with ownership/permissions - check to ensure your buckets/tmp directory is accessible & writable by the user under which you are running stellar-core - some adjustments with `chown` & `chmod` might resolve your issue.

It would help if you include more details about your stellar-core environment; e.g. is it Stellar's quickstart docker, or SatoshiPay's docker image?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo stellar-core` instead.